# Mono for droid app size

Tags: android, xamarin.android

what would be typical app size made with mono droid? I'm talking about "hello world" type of app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With full linking enabled, currently the Hello World sample app is around 4MB in size. I say currently because I know the team is always working on improving the linker to bring app size down even more, so it's likely to go down even further in the future.

You can read about the linker [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking).

Comment: The next major release will shrink the size of the HelloWorld sample from 4.2MB to 2.8MB.

Comment: In case anyone wants confirmation of jonp's comment: using Mono for Android v4.2.4, I just spun up a new "Android Application" project template that resulted in an APK of 2.9MB.