# Xamarin and Mono compared to ADT

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono, xamarin.android, adt, xamarin

I'm a developer, with years of experience in C# as well as Java.
I have developed a few ADT projects for my Nexus One Android 2.23 phone.

I am considering further mobile development and I heard of [Mono for Android/iOS](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) and [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/). At first I thought Mono would recode to Java, but now I understand that it compiles to native C code and runs over mono libs.

So I was wondering how much bloat does this add to apps, as I believe size of download is directly linked to number of downloads (I myself sometimes don't download something due to it being > 1MB)

If there is someone here who uses Mono I would love to hear from your experiences.

I understand there is a [Visual Studio 2010 Plugin for Mono](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/05/01/plug-in-to-mono.aspx). Do you recommend it?

Comment: Then you should move on to ADT and believe it is the best. I think Xamarin has made it very clear why they created Mono for Android (pros and cons), so I don't see any necessarity to discuss it here.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294346/mono-for-droid-app-size

Comment: @LexLi why? Please provide a link to why Xamarin created Mono for Android. Thanks.

Comment: @kenny, there are way too many posts from Miguel's blog http://blog.xamarin.com/author/migueldeicaza/, such as http://blog.xamarin.com/2012/05/01/android-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I was wondering how much bloat does this add to apps, as I believe size of download is directly linked to number of downloads (I myself sometimes don't download something due to it being >1MB .... )

Monodroid apps are usually somewhat around 5 Megabytes (if [Linked](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/linking)) because the runtime is embedded in the app.

> If there is someone here who uses Mono I would love to hear from your experiences.

All in all i'm pretty happy with Monodroid. Java tutorials on Android are easy to translate or if too big you can create [Bindings](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Binding_a_Java_Library_%28.jar%29). I've only done one project on Mono so my experiences are limited but thus far i've expected nothing that would make me regret my choice. On the other hand, if you're familiar with Java (and like coding in Java) their is no reason to switch over except for Cross Plattform apps (see [Monocross](http://monocross.net/)).

The VisualStudio plugin is necessary to develop in VisualStudio. The new version comes with a Layout Designer like the Android Eclipse plugin. I'd recommend you download the trail version from Xamarin and try it (the trail has no expiration date, it lets you only deploy to an emulator)

Comment: is is possible to download the libraries and just link to them ? like .NET Framework, or Connectivity Symbian Libs for Nokia's old phones, etc? From what I read in your "Linked" Bindings, There is only a smart mechanism for embedding a smaller subset of classes used by your app. Is there no way of allowing the user to install the framework once ?

Comment: Android itself doesn't really allow for that. However, for the types of applications you would normally use MonoTouch, the graphical assets will be the main part of the download package anyway. Newer games or fancy applications are now far over 20MB on Android Play and that doesn't stop people from using them.

Comment: [Dev comment](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Feature-Request-Shared-Release-Runtime-Deployment-td5469997.html#a5483563) on that subject